# Is it possible to use redis as a database in nestJS? (Not as a cache service)

Tags: redis, nestjs, typeorm

Before question

- I do understand using redis as a DB is a bad idea with the risk of losing in-memory data.
- Lagacy Data made with old javascript server are piled up in redis DB, and which left me (and nestJS) no choice but redis.

Is it possible to use redis as a database in NestJs?
Or what's recommended way to do it in NestJS, it it's not recommended what could be the reason?

If possible, it's most ideal to hide redis's implementation (similar to typeorm mysql or typeorm mongodb)

Comment: it's possible to use redis in a nestjs app, like in any other nodejs app. Also, read about [Redis persistence](https://redis.io/docs/manual/persistence/)

Answer (score 1):

I have used this package for this purpose:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-redis

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).